# Scraping table in wikipedia with Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the table with postal codes of Toronto in this wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M).

Regardless I use the pandas method or beautifulSoup it just won't work although others reported that it should work. Kindly asking you to give your hints:

Pandas:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]
```

beautifulSoup:

According other guys the output table by use of codes in image should be as the table in image 'expexted output with beautifulSoup'

output of beautifulSoup

[image]

Expected output with beautifulSoup

[image]

Comment: Not sure if there is a magical way with `pandas` but why don't you just scrape it like this: `for each td in for each tr, postal code = text inside <p>, if not <a> in <span> status = not_assigned else borough: text in first <a>, neighborhood: text in second <a>`

Answer (score 0):

You are asking too much! Pandas is great at parsing rectangular HTML tables, and here it does it perfectly:

- it gives 9 columns from M1x to M9x
- it gives 20 rows from MyA to MyZ (not using all letters)

Here you would like to have it parse *inside* the cells. Sorry but you will have to code it yourself. For example you could easily parse the first row with:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]
dfA = df.iloc[0].str.extractall(r'(M\d\w)([^\(\(]*)(?:\((.*)\))?')
```

it gives for `dfA`:

```
           0                                             1                                  2
  match                                                                                      
0 0      M1A                                  Not assigned                                NaN
1 0      M2A                                  Not assigned                                NaN
2 0      M3A                                    North York                          Parkwoods
3 0      M4A                                    North York                   Victoria Village
4 0      M5A                              Downtown Toronto         Regent Park / Harbourfront
5 0      M6A                                    North York  Lawrence Manor / Lawrence Heights
6 0      M7A  Queen's Park / Ontario Provincial Government                                NaN
7 0      M8A                                  Not assigned                                NaN
8 0      M9A                                     Etobicoke                   Islington Avenue
```